# CodeIgniter: Populating a table (HTML/ form) from database (table)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to fill in a table in my view with the data extracted from a database table. However when I tried this, it returned error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\bit\application\views\admin\add_new_room.php on line 32
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $row): { ?> // Line 32
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['room_number'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['rt_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['housekeeping_status'];?></td>
</tr>    
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
function index() {
    $this->load->model('admin/edit_other_details');     
    $roomType['rt_name'] = $this->edit_other_details->get_room_details();
    $data['query'] = $this->edit_other_details->roomsTable();
    $tmp = array_merge($roomType, $data);
    $this->load->view('/admin/add_new_room', $tmp);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function roomsTable() {
    $query = $this->db->select(array('room_number','rt_name'))->get('rooms');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you forgot to return data in your model.

try this

**Model**

```
 function roomsTable() {
   $query = $this->db->select(array('room_number','rt_name'))->get('rooms');
   return $query;  //<---here
}
```

Comment: Thank you and you were quick. It worked! Now I have to wait for few minutes to accept this as the answer by the way. :)